# Implementing fork on JRuby

Tags: ruby, fork, jruby, ffi

I am trying to implement `fork` in `JRuby`. I am monkeypatching `fork` which internally uses FFI to execute a fork call. It then returns child pid.

```
require 'ffi'
module Exec
  extend FFI::Library
  ffi_lib FFI::Library::LIBC
  attach_function :fork, [], :int
end

def fork
  pid = Exec.fork
  if pid == 0
    yield if block_given?
    return nil
  else
    return pid
  end
end
```

Is this the correct way to address the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Whilst that might seem like it works under JRuby, it will be unreliable.

You can't fork the JVM and reliably run java (and hence ruby) code in the child - when a process forks, it only duplicates the thread that executes the fork in the child, and may leave data structures in an inconsistent state.

Thats why fork() is not implemented in JRuby itself.